# Cron job to mount encrypted sparse bundle

Tags: macos, cron

I can run the following command in terminal to mount an encrypted sparsebundle where the bundle password is stored in the keychain.

```
hdiutil attach '/Volumes/Backup/Mac1.sparsebundle'
```

I would like to have that command run on a schedule, so I'm using CronniX to create a cron job with that command.  But, when it runs at the scheduled time, nothing happens.  When I check the cron daemon mail in terminal, it says the following:

```
hdiutil: attach failed - Authentication error
```

I'm assuming that it isn't able to read the password from keychain?  I don't know.  Hoping somebody can shed some light on things, or point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hdiutil depends on some environment variables. Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html) (ENVIRONMENT section). So, probably the environment is different when you run from terminal and from cron. According to error, I think this is due to absence of  **com_apple_diskimages_insecureHTTP**. However the same effect will give adding **-insecurehttp** to the arguments or specify SSL certificate with -cacert/-capath.